Laravel - Sort Parent list by relation attribute
I'm trying to sort list of orders with revise date but it is not sorting with this code. please guide.
class Order extend Model
{
    public function revise()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Revise::class,'order_id');
    }
}

class Revise extend Model
{
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class,'id');
    }
}

Order::with('revise')->orderBy('revise.date','asc')->paginate(15); //Now orders are not being 


Eloquent doesn't sort that way because it loads the model and the relationship separately. Perhaps you should use a join this way;
Order::join('revises', 'orders.id', '=', 'revises.order_id')
        ->orderBy('revises.date', 'asc')
        ->with('revise')
        ->paginate(15);


if i join then with('revise') doesn't work... revise object in response becomes null
{
revise:null
}

I've updated my original comment. The change should work for you.

i did exactly that and still receiving revise null but it is sorting fine.... i need revise object too in the main object with orders. in fact the order is also related with items. after doing this orderitems are also empty []
{
revise:null,
order_items:[]
}
